# RPi as a Dolby Amp?

Tags: pi-2, audio-playback

I have bought a new Smart TV but the sound is a bit disappointing. So I was wonder if using an RPi with some sort of on board amplifier would work; either normal sound to a speaker and Dolby.
Is this a reasonable way to go... perhaps buying an external amplifier?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you want to achieve? To make your TV louder? Something else?

Comment: I read it this way: Smart TV with crappy sound -> want better sound and have some spare 3-way speakers -> want use the Pi as an Amp for thos speakers while watching TV.  ===> The answer to that is: why not buying an Amp in the first place and hook it up to your TV? that way also the RPi will benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kodi, you can follow [this tutorial.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/kodi-raspberry-pi-media-center/)

Fairly deep into the page, it mentions sound quality. You can use the [HiFiBerry](https://www.hifiberry.com/build/guides/) to provide better sound quality. I believe the HiFi will work with standard 5:1 surround sound.
It functions both as the Pi's power source and as an on-board amplifier for really nice sound quality.

Hope that helps!